# How would I detect when an input box is unfocused

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-animations

I need to know when an input box is unfocused, but I can't figure out how to.

I HAVE been trying to use `input:not(:focus)`, but it doesn't work for me. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuPkO.gif) is a video of that happening. If you don't want to watch the video, here's a quick summary:
I want the input box to be animated whenever you focus/unfocus. Using `input:not(:focus)`, it happens instantly instead of the 0.5 seconds that I set it to, and removing `input:not(:focus)` makes it animated, but it instantly goes back when I unfocus the input box.

Comment: so you want to make a transition on input border when focusing in and out, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you want to achieve, here I set the transition to 500ms, if you want it slower set it to 1s, but 500ms is sufficient for input field.

```css
input{
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* border-color set to #444 at
  beginning of the transition "no focus" */
  border: 3px solid #444;
  transition: border-color 1s ease-out;
  outline: none;
  
}
input:focus{
  border-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be to style all elements of the type you wish to animate, for example `input[type=text]`, with a different style for the `:focus` state and animating between them (unless I'm misunderstanding something in your question), as follows:

```css
:root {
  /* using CSS custom properties to define the
     colors in one place, for use everywhere
     (within the descendants of the element
     in which they're defined, which is everything
     for the :root (<html>, in browsers) element: */
  --colorOne: hsl(300deg 100% 100% / 1);
  --colorTwo: hsl(300deg 95% 90% / 1);
}

form {
  inline-size: clamp(30rem, 70%, 900px);
  margin-inline: auto;
}
fieldset {
  gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-columns: max-content;
  place-items: center;
}

label {
  border-radius: 50rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: start;
  margin-block: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

label:focus-within {
  outline: 0.2rem solid var(--colorTwo);
}

.labelText {
  flex-basis: max-content;
  text-align: end;
}

.labelText::after {
  content: ': ';
}

input {
  /* styling the default state of the <input>
     elements: */
  background-color: var(--colorOne);
  padding-inline-start: 0.5rem;
  /* the transition will occur on the 'way out'
     of this state, and on the 'way into' this
     state; it's worth noting that I set the
     transition duration to 750ms (0.75s) in 
     order to make it more obvious, obviously
     adjust this to your use-case: */
  transition: background-color 750ms linear;
}

input:focus {
  /* styling the focused state: */
  --colorOne: var(--colorTwo);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Demo</legend>
    <label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="input one">
  <span class="labelText">Label for input one</span>
</label>
    <label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="input two">
  <span class="labelText">Label for input one</span>
</label>
    <label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="input three">
  <span class="labelText">Label for input one</span>
</label>
    <label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="input four">
  <span class="labelText">Label for input one</span>
</label>
    <label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="input five">
  <span class="labelText">Label for input one</span>
</label>
    <label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="input six">
  <span class="labelText">Label for input one</span>
</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```